# Gradle error while importing play-services-contextmanager

Tags: android, build.gradle, google-awareness

While cloning [Aware](https://github.com/hitherejoe/Aware) repo in my Android Studio, synced gradle and I got below message:

> Failed to sync Gradle project 'app'
>
> Error:Could not find
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.2.0. Required
>   by:
>       Aware:app:unspecified

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.2.0'` is already there in my build.gradle

See build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hitherejoe.aware"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
}
```

Help needed to build project. Can any one say what am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

The Awareness API dependency has been renamed to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness`. Your compile statement should be as follows:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:9.6.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version is 9.2.1.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.2.1
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Okay, then "Error:Could not find" means 1) You have network problems and it can't be downloaded or 2) You have to open the SDK Manager and add the Google Play Services Repository

Answer (score 0):

You should download Google Play services to your Android Studio with the SDK Manager.